# Rails 4 check_box_tag disabled not working?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this simple tag in my view:

```
<label class="checkbox_label">
     <%= check_box_tag 'view_accounts', :disabled => true  %>
      View Bank Accounts
</label> <br>
```

I'm trying to disable it because its just an overview of an activerecord. But to my surprise its not working. I tried every format I know to declare the checkbox disabled.

Anything else I'm missing?

-Using Rails 4, Firefox

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[check_box_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag)

```
<%= check_box_tag 'view_accounts', 'true', false, :disabled => true  %>
```

It takes 4 arguments

- Field_name, ("view_accounts")
- Value to be sent on checked, (eg -> `params[:view_accounts] => 'true', on checked`)
- By default mark checkbox as checked/unchecked (eg -> `true => checked, false => unchecked`)
- And HTML options (eg -> `:disabled => true`)

Comment: Thanks! Will accept after a minute. Still a newbie, I thought I only need the disabled option!

Comment: @Theresa Let me know for any further guidance as well :)

Comment: Thank you in advance! :) Trying my best